# C++ Rvalue arrgument and move

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to understand the difference between rvalue formal parameter and call by value parameter.

When I called fun(move(Demo{}) I see only default constructor called once. 
While I called gun(move(Demo{}) I see default constructor and rval constructor called.  Please some one help me to understand the behaviour of && formal argument type, uses of && in functions/member functions.

compilers clang++ , g++ , vc++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class Demo {
    int i = 10;
public:
    Demo(){
        i = 40;
    }
    Demo(Demo && p) {
        i = p.i + 20;
        cout << "I am in Demo && " << endl;
    }
    Demo & operator = (Demo & p) {
        cout << "I am in operator && " << endl;
    }
    Demo & operator = (Demo && p) {
        i = p.i + 10;
        cout << "I am in operator && " << endl;
    }
    ~Demo(){
        cout << "I am in ~Demo " << i << endl;
    }
};

void fun(Demo & d) {
    cout << "fun( &) " << endl;
    cout << " -- End --  " << endl;
}

void fun(Demo && d) {
    cout << "fun( && ) " << endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << "Lvalur reference : " << is_lvalue_reference<decltype(d)>::value << endl;
    cout << "Rvalue Refernce  : " << is_rvalue_reference<decltype(d)>::value << endl;

    cout << " -- End --  " << endl;
}

void gun(Demo d) {
    cout << "gun( ) " << endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << "Lvalur reference : " << is_lvalue_reference<decltype(d)>::value << endl;
    cout << "Rvalue Refernce  : " << is_rvalue_reference<decltype(d)>::value << endl;
    cout << " -- End --  " << endl;
}
int main() {
    cout << "Main begin " << endl;
    fun(move(Demo{}));
    cout << "------------------- " << endl;
    gun(move(Demo{}));
    cout << "Main End " << endl;
}
```

## //Output

```
Main begin
fun( && )
Lvalur reference : false
Rvalue Refernce  : true
 -- End --
I am in ~Demo 40
-------------------
I am in Demo &&
gun( )
Lvalur reference : false
Rvalue Refernce  : false
 -- End --
I am in ~Demo 60
I am in ~Demo 40
Main End
```

Comment: You are aware of that you have potential undefined behavior in your assignment operator functions, because you don't return anything?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?  Is something about the result counter to what you expected?

Comment: for function void fun(Demo && a) {} when we call fun(move(Demo{}) is the object moved to fun()? , and i see the out put as R-value Reference  : true   in  fun(&&)  where as in gun(Demo d) -  L-value and R-value  reference both false  but the R-value constructor is called for when we pass object to gun()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: an rvalue reference behaves mainly like an usual non-const reference (i mean, a non-const lvalue reference) and in your code it's basically the same as providing lvalue references instead of rvalue references (set aside the traits which differentiate them).
The difference is that when you pass an rvalue reference to a function/method you're telling it "i won't use that anymore, go ahead, do anything you want with it".

Longer answer: rvalue references appeared because you can initialize or assign objects with temporaries, but without them you had to:
 - build a temporary
 - pass a const reference of the temporary to the methof/function
 - clear the muting object
 - sometimes reallocate memory to hold the temporary's contents
 - copy the temporary's contents
 - destroy the temporary
In short, we were performing an unneeded (and potentially expensive) copy whereas we could have simply "moved" the ownership of the temporary's contents to the muted object (when possible).

Rvalue references were introduced so that we could have a type to represent objects in the end of their lifetime which can be freely modified because they won't be used any further anyway.
They are noted with `&&` (not to be mistaken for "universal references" which also use `&&` in a template deduction context).
The difference between passing by value and passing by rvalue reference is that passing value will call the copy constructor and provide you with a fresh instance of that object, whereas passing by rvalue reference (as i said before) behaves exactly the same as passing an usual non-const reference.
However, we don't use usual non-const references because they don't have the "same semantics" and that it would be problematic if a constructor mistook our lvalue reference for an rvalue reference and thrashed our object with its move constructor while we intended to use the copy constructor.

Comment: for funcition void fun(Demo && a) {} when we call fun(move(Demo{})

Comment: for function void fun(Demo && a) {} when we call fun(move(Demo{}) is the object moved to fun()? , and i see the out put as R-value Reference  : true   in  fun(&&)  where as in gun(Demo d) -  L-value and R-value  reference both false  but the R-value constructor is called for when we pass object to gun()

Comment: `gun(Demo d)` takes its parameter by value, which means that you will construct a fresh instance of `Demo` when you call `gun`. Since you're passing an rvalue reference to `gun` the constructor, he chooses to build this new instance of `Demo` is its move constructor: `Demo::Demo(Demo&&)`. However, the gun's argument is a value, not an rvalue reference, even though it has been built with an rvalue reference. Conversely, when you call `fun` with an rvalue reference, no constructor is called: you simply pass a reference (you don't try to create a new instance).

Comment: Got it - Thanks a lot